# Why is this Linux binary (SCons output) not executing?

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2, scons

Here's another variation on the "why doesn't my file run" question.

I have a Linux executable that is one of the compilation outputs from these [instructions](http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-linux/) (summary: download Mongo source and run "scons --ssl all")

There were no errors during compilation, but when I run it, I get this output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10 mongo]$ ./mongo
-bash: ./mongo: Permission denied

[ec2-user@ip-10 mongo]$ sudo ./mongo
sudo: unable to execute ./mongo: Permission denied
```

It *is* executable

```
[ec2-user@ip-10 mongo]$ ls -al mongo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 8545720 May  7 13:41 mongo
```

It appears to be a well-formed file

```
[ec2-user@ip-10 mongo]$ file mongo
mongo: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0x910b4f1d
2799940d47b7a064282ad825f38c6067, stripped
```

I'm continuing to look at scons, my environment, and various mailing lists, but I'm not sure what the problem is.  Any advice?

Further details:
This is an Amazon image,

```
Linux ip-10 3.2.39-6.88.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Mar 2 05:13:37 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It has Python 2.6.8, SCons 2.0.1, and Mongo 2.4.3 installed locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like possibly the file system you are executing from is mounted with the `noexec` option.  Check the output of `mount | grep noexec` and see if your file system is listed.

If so, you'll either need to remount without `noexec` (if you have sufficient permissions and want to do that) or copy/build into a directory where you will be allowed to execute it.

Comment: I'm slapping my forehead here, that was exactly the problem.  The compilation uses up a lot of space and so I did it on the drive with the most free space.  Which happened to be mounted with noexec.  Thanks!